# Is it possible to use scp and change a filename to $date

Tags: shell, date, cron, scp, cp

So I have this script that creates a file called "myfile.txt" this name will never change.

I have 2 servers srv01 and srv02

srv01:**/home/user/scriptdata/myfile.txt** is the file I want to move to srv02

I want this file to arrive at srv02 in the following format

srv02:**/home/user/scriptoutput/$date.txt**

Is there an easy way to do this?
So far I have been using `scp /home/user/scriptdata/myfile.txt 12.34.56.78:/home/user/scriptoutput/day-month-year.txt` manually

Comment: `scp /home/user/scriptdata/myfile.txt 12.34.56.78:/home/user/scriptoutput/$(date +%-d-%B-%Y).txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
scp /home/user/scriptdata/myfile.txt 12.34.56.78:/home/user/scriptoutput/data_$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M).txt
```

This worked! thanks **jhnc** for ur answer